# How to search my threads based on some key words?

Tags: support, discussion

As I have already many threads in some StackExchange sites, sometime I would like to be able to search among them, for instance, based on some key words.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The API v2 provides support for `/search`:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?site=[site]&intitle=[search string]
```

If you want to constrain this to your posts, v2's `/search/advanced` path allows you to filter by user, [or by basically anything else](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search):

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?site=[site]&title=[search string]&user=[your user ID]
```

Beware - `/search` calls the title parameter `intitle`, while `/search/advanced` calls it `title`.

Answer (score 0):

You can search any Stack Exchange site for some keywords using the [`/search` method](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage/methods/search):

> ```
> http://api.[site].com/1.1/search?intitle=[search string]
> ```

According to the [usage documentation](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage), the `intitle` parameter is:

> A string that must appear verbatim in the title of a question

Here is an example URL:

> [`http://api.askubuntu.com/1.1/search?intitle=install+firefox`](http://api.askubuntu.com/1.1/search?intitle=install+firefox)

Notice that all of the responses contain the string `install firefox` in their title.

Comment: Thanks... what if I just want to search among **my** posts?

Comment: @SoftTimur: Unfortunately there is no way of doing that at the moment.

Comment: @SoftTimur, you should post a feature-request for more search options,